# $I+J=A\Rightarrow I^m+J^n=A$ in the noncommutative case?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Suppose we have an ring $A$ and two ideals $I$ and $J$ such that $I+J=A$. Then, if $A$ is commutative, for all $m,n\in \mathbb{Z}_{>0}$, we have $I^m+J^n=A$. I am wondering whether this is true for the case when $A$ is not commutative. Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming $A$ is unital, let $x \in I$ and $y \in J$ such that $x + y = 1$. Then
$$xy = x(1 - x) = x - x^2 = (1 - x)x = yx,$$
so the binomial theorem applies and the proof proceeds exactly as in the commutative case (use the binomial theorem to show that $(x + y)^{m+n-1}$ is in $I^m + J^n$).

In the non-unital case, this is false even for commutative rings: $4\mathbb{Z} + 6\mathbb{Z} = 2\mathbb{Z}$, but $(4 \mathbb{Z})^2 + (6 \mathbb{Z})^2 = 4\mathbb{Z} \neq 2\mathbb{Z}$.